# Flask-SocketIO making bad requests

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, flask

I have a flask application where i use SocketIO for chatting, but i can't seem to make a propper request to my server.

When i establish the connection everything works fine

```
@socketio.on('connected')
def on_connect(json):
print(json)
print(f'client established a connection.. with ip: 
{request.remote_addr}')
```

but whenever i send a message the request just waits, and then it gives a bad request back

```
@socketio.on('send message')
def handle_custom_vent(json):
print('received event ' + str(json))
res = make_test_obj()
socketio.emit('my response', res, 
callback=message_received(res, json))
```

it worked fine earlier, but now this problem came all of the sudden.

[image: here is the bad request]

I'm using a javascript library to make the socket request.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
....
   this.socket = io('http://localhost:5000/')


  //works fine
  this.socket.emit('connected', {
    msg: 'hello'
  })


 //holds and gives bad request
 this.socket.on('my response', (message) =>{
    this.setState({
      messages: [...this.state.messages, message]
    }, () => console.log('message received was ', message) )
  })
}
```